# Style inheritance in thmtools

Tags: amsthm, thmtools

In the following MWE I'm defining two theorem styles, `remark` and `definition`, which should be identical except for a few key-value pairs.

I'd like to reuse the style of `remark` in the declaration of `definition`, but simply using `style=remark` inside it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  postheadspace=.5em,
]{remark}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  % style=remark, % <-- is there a way to make this work?
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  postheadspace=.5em,
  notefont=\normalfont,
]{definition}

\declaretheorem[
  style=remark,
  name=Remark,
]{remark}

\declaretheorem[
  style=definition,
  name=Definition,
]{definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{remark}[ name={foo} ]
  This is a remark.
\end{remark}

\begin{definition}[ name={bar} ]
  This is a definition.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of the `style` key available in `\declaretheoremstyle`. Also posted on the corresponding thmtools [github issue](https://github.com/muzimuzhi/thmtools/issues/15). Since amsthm predefines `remark` and `definition` styles, I've renamed your styles to `myremark` and `mydefinition` (it will still work the way you have it, but renaming avoids confusion in this example).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\makeatletter

\define@key{thmstyle}{style}{%
  \thmt@inheritstyle{#1}%
}

\def\thmt@inheritstyle#1{
  \ifcsname thmt@style@#1@setdefaultkeys\endcsname%
  \csname thmt@style@#1@setdefaultkeys\endcsname%
  \else
  \PackageError{thmtools}{No style `#1' defined}{}%
  \fi
}

\renewcommand\declaretheoremstyle[2][]{%
  \def\thmt@style{#2}%
  \@xa\def\csname thmt@style \thmt@style @defaultkeys\endcsname{}%
  \thmt@declaretheoremstyle@setup
  \kvsetkeys{thmstyle}{#1}%
  \thmt@declaretheoremstyle{#2}%
  \@xa\def\csname thmt@style@\thmt@style @setdefaultkeys\endcsname{% ADDED
    \kvsetkeys{thmstyle}{#1}% ADDED
  }% ADDED
}

\def\thmt@style@plain@setdefaultkeys{}

\def\thmt@style@definition@setdefaultkeys{%
  \kvsetkeys{thmstyle}{%
    bodyfont=\normalfont
  }%
}

\def\thmt@style@remark@setdefaultkeys{%
  \kvsetkeys{thmstyle}{%
    spaceabove=0.5\topsep,
    spacebelow=0.5\topsep,
    headfont=\itshape,
    bodyfont=\normalfont
  }%
}

\makeatother

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  postheadspace=.5em,
]{myremark}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  style=myremark,
  notefont=\normalfont,
]{mydefinition}

\declaretheorem[
  style=myremark,
  name=Remark,
]{remark}

\declaretheorem[
  style=mydefinition,
  name=Definition,
]{definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{remark}[name=foo]
  This is a remark.
\end{remark}

\begin{definition}[name=bar]
  This is a definition.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image: thms]

As I mention in the github issue, it may be better to give it a name like `inherit-style`.